# Basic Access Authentication: Encoding of ':' and non-ASCII code points

Tags: http, http-headers, base64

For the base64-user-pass value in the Authorization header, is there a standard/de facto way to base64-encode usernames and passwords which contain code points which don't fit into an OCTET, or usernames which contain a colon (which is explicitly prohibited by RFC 2617)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes, but only proposed and not implemented (AFAIK): https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7617.html#charset

2) No.

Comment: Spot on answer! I guess it is easier to put restrictions on user-ids than on passwords.